# How to get absolute path for file download from another drive?

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0

I need to give a download link to a pdf file which is in D: drive.

My website is hosted in C: drive of same system.

How can i give a download link to my pdf file in D: drive in my website which is hosted in C: drive?

Comment: Have you tried: String str =  HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath; ?

Comment: sorry about that.. im new to stackoverflow. will do it soon. and about the path.. i just need to give a download link. but i was not able to refer to a file in D:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, I try to never expose downloadable files directly.

Instead I write an ASHX handler ("Generic Handler" in Visual Studio) that fetches and sends the file to the user's browser.

Basically, you pass a unique ID to the handler (e.g. the pure file name) and the handler does the rest to fetch the file locally and stream it to the browser like in this pseudo code:

```
public class MyHandler :
    IHttpHandler
{
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        var fileName = Request[@"fn"];
        var filePath = Path.Combine(@"C:\My\Fixed\File\Path", fileName );

        Response.ContentType = @"application/pdf";

        Response.AddHeader(
            @"Content-Disposition", 
            @"attachment; filename=" + Path.GetFileName(filePath));
        Response.AddHeader(
            @"Content-Length",
            new FileInfo(filePath).Length );

        Response.WriteFile(filePath);
        Response.End();
    }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get { return false; }
    }
}
```

The advantages of such an approach is that you have full control over whether and how the file gets downloaded. Some scenarios include:

- Permission checking whether user is logged in and may download the file.
- Streaming with different file names to the client.
- Logging file download to a database.
- ...

Comment: I was not able to open the pdf file. its says file may be corrupt . so i tried to download a txt file . when i opened that file the content was missing. i got the following as the file content "<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC ' -//W3C//DT".

Comment: So you remove me 15 reputation points, because my _pseudo code_ didn't work? Of course you have to adjust it to your need.

Comment: sorry..its not that.. it was'nt working..   Response.WriteFile(filePath); was not able to map to another drive. that was my actual problem.it can download only from projet folders

Comment: If your server is able to access the the share, (i.e. connectivity and permissions), you are also able to use `WriteFile`. I'm using this in several projects, too.

Answer (score 0):

You can mount the drive that is currently `D:` to a folder inside your `C:` drive using NTFS junction points, which will make your `D:` drive appear as though it is part of your `C:` drive. All problems solved.

Usage details for `mklink`, a program included with Windows that facilitates the creation, management and deletion of all kinds of links (including junction points), can be found [at the Microsoft TechNet documentation center](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753194%28WS.10%29.aspx).

Alternatively, you may be interested in symbolic links and hard links, which are similar in nature (though have subtle differences).